# Ext.Store Send multiple data at once

Tags: java, javascript, rest, jackson, extjs4.1

I am creating a one to many form in one transaction. I really need the record to be created entirely, or not at all. I have implemented a back code using java to rollback all operation should one of the data does not meet the requirement. Interface is using extjs, and I have REST interface with Jackson.

The problem is, how is the best way for ExtJS 4 to send everything in a particular form along with all detail records to a URL? Despite anything I have done, Ext.Store seems to send the data one by one.

Well, in short, I need the Ext.Store to POST something like this as raw with application/json content:

```
{
    id: '',
    party: 3,
    machine: 'x1',
    product: 'pr001',
    runtime: 12,
    materials: [{
        item: 'rm001',
        qty: '39.01',
        align: '9.930'
    }, {
        item: 'rm002',
        qty: '20.03',
        align: '9.0234'
    }]
}
```

The problem is, the child store always send the data as it is entered, and when I set autoSync to false, it still sends them one by one not everything at once through parent store.

Any example code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the way that I do it is through xml but the Idea should be the same
I have the parent store contain a serialize function 
and it looks something like this

```
serialize: function(){
     var store = this;
     var xml = [];
     store.each(function(record){
        xml.push('id:'+record.get(id))
        xml.push('party:'+record.get(party))
        record.materials().each(function(materials_rec){
           xml.push('item:'+materials_rec.get(item));
            ...                 
        });
     });
     return xml.join('');
}
```

so I call this function from the controller and I submit an ajax request that will contain all the records of the parent and child stores